# In, react-native info how to check RN version?

Tags: react-native, version

In Terminal,
react-native: 0.68.0 => 0.60.0
does it mean that this project version is 68 or 60? In pacakge.json, i manually changed it to 0.68 and then npm install. and I checked react-native info.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to change manually react native version because sometimes as per version level some internal files or set up not done properly and it will create issue for running project Use below command for upgrade project

**npx react-native upgrade**

If you want to upgrade specific version then use below command

**npx react-native upgrade 0.68**

after then check react native version It will show 0.68